# Image<TColor, TDepth>.FindContours missing from EmguCV 3.0

Tags: c#, emgucv

The Image.FindContours method is missing, using the latest 3.0 version of Emgu CV. (i guess that is not the only one)

Where can I find them?

Update:

I want to accomplish the same under C#

```
Mat edges; //from canny
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are right - the Image.FindContours() method is missing from the EmguCV 3.0. And there is a lot of others even has not been wrapped by the new [`CvInvoke`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/bb544594-4bf7-5a11-594c-f143b226f1da.htm) wrapper.

But as for the FindContours particular one you can use the snippet below using CvInvoke static methods wrapper:
(suppose imgBinary is the Image object, )

```
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contoursDetected = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
CvInvoke.FindContours(imgBinary, contoursDetected, null, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.List, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
```

And then you can use the obtained contours "array" for example like this:

```
contoursArray = new List<VectorOfPoint>();
int count = contoursDetected.Size;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    using (VectorOfPoint currContour = contoursDetected[i])
    {
        contoursArray.Add(currContour);
    }
}
```

Note that the [`CvInvoke.FindContours()`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/cb24a129-d9ce-57f3-19ad-0eaa27a77317.htm) now doesn't return `Seq<Point>` or `Contour<Point>` structures into the contoursDetected but the `VectorOfVectorOfPoint` which is actually `Point[][]`.

Comment: please explain your answer, add a link\ reference with a quote

Comment: Welcome to SO. @Michael. Even though you had identified the method this author is referring to, it does not solve the issue. The question itself is low quality because there is no code sample or any reference. Please consider explaining further and request for more info from the author.

Comment: The answer is quite useful, except the type of the hierarchy.